# Copy the complete structure of a table in another table

Tags: sql-server

How can I copy the complete structure of a table in another table with PK, FK, etc.

The following query is missing constraints:

```
SELECT top 0 * INTO [DestinationDB].[tableSchema].[tableName] FROM [SourceDB].[tableSchema].[tableName]
```

Comment: there is no one-line command to do this, as each constraint, index, etc needs names which you would need to supply or automate; basically, the answer here is "manually and carefully, but thoughtfully" - or there might be some tools inside SQL Server Explorer

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65734/how-to-create-new-table-with-same-constraints-and-indexes for an explanation and solution

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/duplicate-tables?view=sql-server-ver16 - does this link solve your problem?

Comment: Please do not *SHOUT* at us (in your title); it's is considered quite rude.

Comment: Sorry @ThomA  it's the first time I've asked a question so I need to get familiar. In general I am used to always putting the title in capital letters.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is not by construction your own raw SQL, because to recreate keys and other constraints it doesn't have a built in command.

If you have access to SQL Server Management Studio, you can just right click the table and export the definitions, then it will generate all that for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16#ScriptSingleObject